# Why my function is not defined?

Tags: python, list, filter

I don't understand exactly why my function are not found by python.

I Create a function share:

```
def share(item):
    if re.findall(r'\bshare',item):                                                               
        return True                                                                               
    return False
```

and I just want to use this for filter a list

```
item['twurlshort'] = filter(lambda item: not share, item['twurlshort'])
```

But python say: `exceptions.NameError: global name 'share' is not defined`

My filter function are in the same class.
Anyone knows why exactly ?

Comment: In python, you have to prepend `self.` when calling methods in the same class.

Comment: Using `findall` is unnecessary. Just use `re.search`.

Comment: Also, since you're not *calling* your function, `not share` will always be false (because a function reference is true in a Boolean context).

Comment: http://sscce.org is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't lie about this, so your function is not in scope.

Please check that your function is

1. in the top-level scope,
2. or if not, in the same scope as the caller,
3. or that if it is in another module you have imported that module,
4. or if in the same class, you call it attached to an instance

In your case, you need to change two things:

```
Class Whatever:
    def share(self, item):
        # ...

item['twurlshort'] = filter(lambda item: not item.share, item['twurlshort'])
```

Comment: If it's in a class, it also need to be decorated with `@staticmethod` or take `self`.

Comment: staticmethod won't work here unless all items share the same share state -- unlikely

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning - the function doesn't use `self` at all (to the point where it doesn't exist in the OP's definition), so it would be fine as a static method.

Comment: Think of the use case. item.share represents the "shareability" of that specific item. The actual business state is bound to individual items and a static state would not be useful. Probably.